# Spark python most repeated value for each key

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD with format: (date, city). And the data inside is something like this:

```
day1, city1
day1, city2
day1, city2
day2, city1
[...]
```

I need to obtain the most "repeated" city by each day, ie I need the following result:

```
day1, city2
day2, city1
day3, ...
```

Can you help me how to do it in Python?

I tried to do it like a simple wordcount:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], [1]. \
map(lambda y:y,1). \
reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b). \
takeOrdered(1, lambda s:-1*s[1]))).collect()
```

But of course it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be easy if you know SQL. Can you please [edit] your question to include what you've tried?

Comment: Thanks cricket_007 for your comments and apologize if question was not correctly raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a modified wordcount:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
  .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) \
  .map(lambda ((day, city), count): (day, (city, count))) \
  .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: max(x, y, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, that's exactly what I need :)